# Querystring params in websocket api aws issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, websocket, aws-lambda, gateway

I am trying to pass query string through my WebSocket connections by wss://connection_url?queryparam=param

but the lambda function invoked by the connection is not able to read the query param. in fact I printed the integration response received to lambda function and it doesn't show any query param in it. should I need to configure in API gateway to allow query string params please help

Comment: Can you post your Lambda code?

You _should_ be able to see queryStringParameters in the event, if you are using Lambda Proxy

Answer (score -1):

Yes, enable `Use Lambda Proxy integration`. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html

Comment: Can you please be more precise here. I have my proxy integration enabled and still i am unable to see the queryStringParameters in the event object. Thanks